# Protect apk installation with password

Tags: android

I am making an android application.To use my application user has to first create an account on a web server.He/She will be provided user id and password while creating Account on that web server.After that when he/she try to install my apk from Google play or from SD card,he/she will be asked to provide that user id and password that is given from that web server.If he/she enters correct user id and password then only my apk will be allowed to install on user's android device else my apk will not be installed on his/her android device.How is it possible?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can accomplish exactly what you want. I have never heard anything about a protected password .apk.

A possible workaround would be to not upload your app to google play store, making the only possible way to download it through your server. There you can postergate the download of the app behing the user registration.

In addition, you can also implement some code in your android app to ask for some credentials in the first launch (obtained in the registration process), and if thery are not provided, the app doen't let the user have access to its services.

There are multiple combinations.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No,that is not helpful.Bcoz user has to download my app from Google play.However I appreciate your guide.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't protect the installation process, but the sign in instead. When user starts an app, he'll be prompted to enter credentials. What you describe doesn't make any sense. Just take a look at other apps(Whatsapp, Facebook, Gmail etc.)

Comment: I know my requirement is unusual.But it is my requirement.

Comment: @user3571215 I don't think you can do it without interfering with the OS.